# Firebase Stripe Extension: No such payment_intent, a similar object exists in live mode, but a test mode key was used to make this request

Tags: android, firebase, stripe-payments

I'm currently using Firebase's Stripe extension to process payments on an Android application. I was trying to use Stripe's test cards to test the integration, so I set all the keys (publishable key on client-side, Stripe API key with restricted access and Stripe webhook secret in the extension configuration in Firebase) to test mode. But when I tried to make payments, Stripe's mobile Payment Sheet didn't show up, and an error message was showed that reads "No such payment_intent ****, a similar object exists in live mode, but a test mode key was used to make this request".

I did notice the payment intent secrets, customer, and epherameral key secret all appeared in my Firestore database after I followed instructions on Firebase by setting client to "mobile", mode to "payment", amount, and currency in Firestore, but the epheramal key secret has the format ek_live_******* (so I assumed it was in live mode). However, I didn't think I used live mode key anywhere in my project. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are creating live move objects server-side (based on the live mode ephemeral key that is being created) which don't match using your test-mode publishable key client-side. You will need to double-check on the restricted key that you created, and ensure you created a test mode restricted key (it should look like `rk_test_xxx`) and then double-check that your last update to your server-side firebase extension code didn't get cached.

The other thing you can do to gather more details would be to add a log to your firebase extension code [right after `stripe` is initialized](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/blob/next/firestore-stripe-payments/functions/src/index.ts#L32-L40) and then log out `stripe` there and check your firebase logs to ensure that `stripe` is being initialized in test-mode.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I suspected Firebase cached the secret key and webhook secrets in live mode. Do you know how to clear the cache? Also, I'd like to add a log to the extension code, could you tell me how to do that?